# How to call stored procedure in API using EF/SQL Server and check RetVal before processing ResultSet?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I've reduced a .NET Core 6 API for an `Equipment` model to just two columns for testing: `Equipment_Id` and `Description`. During the `POST` (Add), the SQL Server stored procedure will return value 0 or 2 on success and everything works fine.

If I get a return value of 1 (error) with an error message (ex: "Equipment already exists"), the conversion to `Equipment` fails because there is no result set and an exception occurs. I want to examine the return value (`dbParam`) within generating the exception.

How do I execute the stored procedure, examine the return value and then convert the result set to a `List<Equipment>` ?

```
try
{
    // snipped dbParameters creation
    string CommandText = "EXEC @ReturnValue=sp_API_Model_Equipment_WRITE @Equipment_Id=@Equipment_Id OUTPUT,@Description=@Description,@ErrMsg=@ErrMsg OUTPUT";

    var results = await _DbContext.Equipment.FromSqlRaw(CommandText, dbParameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync(); 

    // If the stored procedure detects a problem and returns value 1 (error), 
    // there is no resultset and an exception is generated:
    //
    // Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: 
    // An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'myAPI.Data.DBContext'.
    // System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Equipment_Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
    // at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
    // at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    // at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    // at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
    //

    int ReturnValue = (int)paramReturnValue.Value;

    switch (ReturnValue)
    {
        case 0: // Success
            if (results.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();  // 404

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEquipmentById", new { Equipment_Id = results[0].SerialNum }, results[0]);  // 201 Created

        case 1: // Error
            return BadRequest(paramErrMsg.Value);

        case 2: // Warning (Already Exists)
            if (results.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();  // 404 (Internal Failure)

            return Ok(results[0]);  // 200 OK

        case 99: // Exception
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal exception occurred");
    }

    return BadRequest($"Unknown ReturnValue ${ReturnValue}.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    clsDebug.WriteDebugExc(ex);

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal exception occurred.");
}
```

Comment: Most SQL Server stuff is oriented about *streaming* result sets back to the client. If there are results to stream, it's unlikely that the return value will be produced yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try returning an empty resultset in that case, something like:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
EXEC @ReturnValue=sp_API_Model_Equipment_WRITE @Equipment_Id=@Equipment_Id OUTPUT,@Description=@Description,@ErrMsg=@ErrMsg OUTPUT";

if @ReturnValue = 1
begin
  select * from equipment where 1=0;
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked until it didn't.  Some query results were too complex to run without valid parameters.  Proc needed simply to return != 0 result code.

Answer (score 0):

20/20 hindsight. I was trying too hard to get things working with EF/LINQ (`FromSqlRaw`/`ToListAsync`) methods when a cleaner solution using stock Microsoft.Data.SqlClient was staring me in the face.

I'm now able to call the proc, look at the `ReturnValue` and only if there are Data Rows convert them to a `List.

I've posted the modified code here:

```
try
{
    using (var cmd = _DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        var paramReturnValue = new SqlParameter();

        paramReturnValue.ParameterName = "@ReturnValue";
        paramReturnValue.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        paramReturnValue.Value = 0;
        paramReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramReturnValue);

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var paramErrMsg = new SqlParameter();

        paramErrMsg.ParameterName = "@ErrMsg";
        paramErrMsg.DbType = DbType.String;
        paramErrMsg.Value = "";
        paramErrMsg.Size = 256;
        paramErrMsg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramErrMsg);

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        cmd.CommandText = "sp_API_Model_Equipment_WRITE";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();

        await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync(); // Execute the Proc without Throwing Exc on No Data Rows

        int ReturnValue = (int)paramReturnValue.Value; // Get Return Value from Proc

        switch (ReturnValue)
        {
            case int n when (n == 0 || n == 2): // Success or Already Exists -- Data Rows Exists
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)cmd);  // dbCommand inherits from 
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

                var dv = dt.ToDataList<Equipment>();  // create new List<T> from DataTable

                if (dv.Count == 0)
                    return NotFound();  // 404

                if(ReturnValue == 2)
                    return Ok(dv[0]);  // 200 OK (Already Exists)

                return CreatedAtAction("GetEquipmentById", new { Equipment_Id = dv[0].SerialNum }, dv[0]);  // 201 Created

            case 1: // Error
                return BadRequest(paramErrMsg.Value); // User Error Message created by Proc

            case 99: // Exception (SQL Catch)
                clsDebug.WriteDebugError($"SQL Failure: {ReturnValue} -- {paramErrMsg.Value}"); // Log System Message

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal exception occurred"); // Return User Message
        }

        clsDebug.WriteDebugError($"SQL Failure: Unknown Return Value {ReturnValue} -- {paramErrMsg.Value}"); // Log System Message

        return BadRequest($"Unknown ReturnValue ${ReturnValue}."); // Return User Message
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    clsDebug.WriteDebugExc(ex); // Log Exception

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal exception occurred."); // Return Neutered Message
}
```